# Group two arrays of objects in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have two array of objects. I want to insert the corresponding extraProperty in the "car" array, if found. There may be several extraProperties or none. That is, I wanted to add, when an extraProperty was found for the respective car, an array with the list of extraproperties found.

Each extraProperties consists of an object with the following properties: Id, Name, Value.

Code:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$Types,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$PathFile,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3, ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$PathPropertyFile 
)
    $profiles_list = Import-Csv $PathFile -Header Id, model, Type Delimiter ";" 
    $extraProperties_list = Import-Csv $PathPropertyFile -Header ProfileId,Name,Value -Delimiter ";" # Get-Content -Path $pathFile  
        foreach($p in $car_list) {
                $Property =  $property_list.Where({$_.Id -eq $p.Id}) | Select-Object -Property Name,Value
                if(-Not (($null -eq $Property ) -And (@($Property ).Count -eq 0)) ) {
                    $p = $p | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{Properties=$Property }
                } else {
                    $p = $p | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{Properties=@()}
                }
        }
```

Data sample:

PropertyFile.csv

```
Id     | Name     | Value
504953 | Example1 | Value1
504953 | Example2 | Value2
504955 | Example3 | Value3
```

CarFiles.csv

```
Id     | Model  | Type 
504953 | Model1 | 3
504954 | Model1 | 0
504955 | Model3 | 3
```

The problem is that the code is not efficient. The car array reaches 200000 positions and where each position is an object with several properties and the properties array also reaches these values. The script takes endless hours to execute.

Any way to optimize the insertion of a new property within arrays?

Comment: @Olaf I edited the post. Arrays are filled in from an excel.

Comment: Yes, the script is what I shared. I read from two .csv files, and fill the array with the new object based on the as properties array..

Comment: @Olaf I edited the post with a small example. The Carfiles csv file has more than one million recrods and the Property has 200,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if this is faster (we don't know how large the CSV files are), but you could do it like this:

For demo I'm using Here-Strings, but in real life you import the data from files:

```
$profiles_list = Import-Csv $PathFile -Delimiter ";" 
$extraProperties_list = Import-Csv $PathPropertyFile -Delimiter ";"
```

Using your examples:

```
$profiles_list = @"
Id;Model;Type
504953;Model1;3
504954;Model1;0
504955;Model3;3
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$extraProperties_list = @"
Id;Name;Value
504953;Example1;Value1
504953;Example2;Value2
504955;Example3;Value3
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

# get the headers from the Cars
$profileHeaders = $profiles_list[0].PsObject.Properties.Name
# get the new property names from the ExtraProperties Name column
$newHeaders = $extraProperties_list.Name | Where-Object {$profileHeaders -notcontains $_}  | Select-Object -Unique

# add all these new properties to the $profiles_list, for now with $null values
$profiles_list | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($prop in $newHeaders) {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $prop -Value $null
    }
}

# group the $extraProperties_list by the Id column and loop through these groups
$extraProperties_list | Group-Object Id | ForEach-Object {
    $id = $_.Name
    # get an array of profiles with matching Ids
    $profiles = $profiles_list | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $id}
    # and fill in the blanks
    foreach($item in $profiles) {
        foreach($extra in $_.Group) {
            $item.($extra.Name) = $extra.Value
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$profiles_list

# output to new CSV file
$profiles_list | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\CompletedProfiles.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

```
Id       : 504953
Model    : Model1
Type     : 3
Example1 : Value1
Example2 : Value2
Example3 : 

Id       : 504954
Model    : Model1
Type     : 0
Example1 : 
Example2 : 
Example3 : 

Id       : 504955
Model    : Model3
Type     : 3
Example1 : 
Example2 : 
Example3 : Value3
```

Comment: profiles_list = 140000 records and extraProperties_list = 550000 records. The group for an array with 500000 lines takes a long time, it has been running for 1 hour and a half..